# Amazon Route 53 mass update hosted zones

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, command-line-interface, updates

- I have over 200 hosted zones on Route 53.
- I need to **update all these hosted zones' "A records"** at once, and point the A records to amazon load balancer (it was previously pointing to IPv4 address)

Is there a way using **aws cli** or any other tools to perform this task?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: this is easy with a handful of lines of `boto`. If you post your best-effort code, I'm happy to fix/finish it.

Answer (score 0):

Without going too far into it, you should be able to work something out using the CLI. I imagine you could list out the A records using [list-resource-record-sets](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/route53/list-resource-record-sets.html) and then iterate over that with [change-resource-record-sets](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/route53/change-resource-record-sets.html). Sorry I don't have a more detailed answer for you at this moment.

Edit: It should definitely be possible using CLI or boto etc to iterate through the hosted zones and the resource records within, and update them.

Answer (score 0):

You can quickly create all of the resource record sets for an Amazon Route 53 hosted zone by **importing a zone file**.

See: [Creating Resource Record Sets By Importing a Zone File](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/resource-record-sets-creating-import.html)

However, I'm not sure whether this can be used to point to an "ALIAS record", which is the way to configure Route 53 to point to an Elastic Load Balancing service. This is different to the standard `A` record because **a Load Balancer should always be referenced by DNS name** rather than IP Address. It is *not* advisable to create `A` records to load balancers since the IP addresses can change (and often multiple IP addresses are in use). Instead, use the "ALIAS" option in Route 53 to automatically resolve the address, or use a `CNAME` record to point to the DNS name of the Load Balancer.

See: [Choosing Between Alias and Non-Alias Resource Record Sets](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/resource-record-sets-choosing-alias-non-alias.html)

The simplest way might be to import a zone file that contains CNAME records of the load balancers.